# THREE.js - clickable interactive objects.Click on a cube and then appear second cube and i want to make the last cube clickable

Tags: javascript, three.js

[this is what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh5Wk.png).Once you click on the box then i want to appear a second box and when i click on the second box i want the color from the first cube to change.I manage to make the first step but i don't know how to implement the last step, to click on the second cube and then change the color of my original.Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var camera, scene, renderer;
          var geometry, material, mesh;

          init();
          animate();

          function init() {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
              75,
              window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
              0.01,
              1000
            );
            camera.position.z = 2;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2c9b73 });

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.rotation.set(45, 0, 0);
            scene.add(mesh);

            var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
            light.position.set(10, 10, 10);
            scene.add(light);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
              renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
              camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
              camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            });
          }
          var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
          var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
          function onMouseMove(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
            for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
              var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
              var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xce2121 });
              var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
              mesh1.position.y = 1;
              scene.add(mesh1);
            }
          }

          function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            //mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
          }

          window.addEventListener("click", onMouseMove);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can name your mesh.

For say, we can name it as `rotatingMesh` & `staticMesh`.
Naming is required to track on which 3d obj click event is being performed.

Now if I Click on the second cube should turn to yellow, for that you have to listen for click on the 2nd object also (as shown below)

```
for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
  if(intersects[i].object.name === 'staticMesh') {
      // Set rotating mesh color to yellow
      mesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(1,1,0)
  } else {
    var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xce2121 });
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    mesh1.name = 'staticMesh'
    mesh1.position.y = 1;
    scene.add(mesh1);
  }
}
```

Have shown the use case in the below code snippet. 
Kindly let me know if you have any other doubt

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          var camera, scene, renderer;
          var geometry, material, mesh;

          init();
          animate();

          function init() {
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
              75,
              window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
              0.01,
              1000
            );
            camera.position.z = 2;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x2c9b73 });

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            mesh.name = 'rotatingMesh'
            mesh.rotation.set(45, 0, 0);
            scene.add(mesh);

            var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100);
            light.position.set(10, 10, 10);
            scene.add(light);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
              renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
              camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
              camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            });
          }
          var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
          var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
          function onMouseMove(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

            for (var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
              if(intersects[i].object.name === 'staticMesh') {
                  // Set rotating mesh color to yellow
                  mesh.material.color = new THREE.Color(1,1,0)
              } else {
                var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
                var material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xce2121 });
                var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
                mesh1.name = 'staticMesh'
                mesh1.position.y = 1;
                scene.add(mesh1);
              }
            }
          }

          function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            //mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
          }

          window.addEventListener("click", onMouseMove);
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```